# How to Pass a value from mysql to a form field in create view

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a PatientConsultationView with a createview class that creates, and an AllConsultationView that List all consultation. I will like to pass the consultation ID to the PatientObservationView and use it to populate the PatientObservationForm OR, just saved it in the PatientObservation Model without end users havent to enter the ID manually since it can be gotten from the AllConsultationView

views.py

```
class PatientConsultationView(CreateView):
    model = PatientConsultation
    template_name = 'patient/patient_consultation_add.html'
    form_class = PatientConsultationForm
    context_object_name = 'Patient_Consultation'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient_list')

class AllConsultationView(ListView):
    model = PatientConsultation
    template_name = 'patient/all_consultation.html'
    context_object_name = 'All_Patient_Consultation'

    def get_consult_id(self):

        return PatientConsultation.objects.filter(consultation_id=self)

class PatientObservationView(CreateView):
    model = PatientObservation
    template_name = 'patient/patient_observation_add.html'
    form_class = PatientObservationForm
    context_object_name = 'Patient_Observation'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient_list')
```

forms.py

```
class PatientConsultationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = PatientConsultation
        fields = ('patient_id', 'weight', 'temperature', 'blood_pressure', 'pulse', 'oxygen_saturation',
                  'body_mass_index', 'status',)

        widgets = {
            'patient_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient ID'}),
            'weight': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Weight'}),
            'temperature': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Temperature'}),
            'blood_pressure': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Blood Pressure'}),
            'pulse': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Pulse'}),
            'oxygen_saturation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height ', 'placeholder': 'Patient Oxygen Saturation'}),
            'body_mass_index': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Body Mass Index'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient Status',}),
        }


class PatientObservationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = PatientObservation
        fields = {'consultation_id','note_to_laboratories','note_to_pharmacist','note_to_physiotherapist',
                  'note_to_radiologist','medical_advice','medical_report','referral_note'}


        widgets = {
            'consultation_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-height', 'placeholder': 'Patient ID'}),
            'note_to_laboratories': RichTextFormField(),
            'note_to_pharmacist': RichTextFormField(),
            'note_to_physiotherapist': RichTextFormField(),
            'note_to_radiologist': RichTextFormField(),
            'medical_advice': RichTextFormField(),
            'medical_report': RichTextFormField(),
            'referral_note': RichTextFormField(),
```

models.py

```
class PatientConsultation(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing Observation records made by nurses
    """
    PATIENT_CONSULTATION_STATUS = (
        ('1', 'Consulting'),
        ('0', 'Done')
    )

    consultation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    patient_id = models.ForeignKey(PatientProfile)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    temperature = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    pulse = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    oxygen_saturation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body_mass_index = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PATIENT_CONSULTATION_STATUS, default='1')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the model object (in Admin)
        """
        return str(self.consultation_id)


class PatientObservation(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing doctors report of a particular episode
    """
    consultation_id = models.ForeignKey(PatientConsultation)
    note_to_pharmacist = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    note_to_laboratories = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    note_to_physiotherapist = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    note_to_radiologist = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    referral_note = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    medical_report = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    medical_advice = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the model object (in Admin)
        """
        return self.consultation_id
```

My PatientConsultationAdd.html template formTag

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="submit_form"  action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-wizard">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Select Consultation ID
                                    <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.consultation_id }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Note To Laboratories
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.note_to_laboratories }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Note To Pharmacist
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.note_to_pharmacist }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Note To Physiotherapist
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.note_to_physiotherapist }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Note To Radiologist
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.note_to_radiologist }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Medical Advice
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.medical_advice }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Medical Report
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.medical_report }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="">Referral Note
                                    <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {{ form.referral_note }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^patient/$', views.PatientList.as_view(), name='patient_list'),
    url(r'^patient/new/$', views.PatientCreate.as_view(), name='patient_new'),
    url(r'^patient/detail/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.PatientDetails.as_view(), name='patient_details'),
    url(r'^patient/update/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.PatientUpdate.as_view(), name='patient_update'),
    url(r'^patient/delete/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.PatientDelete.as_view(), name='patient_delete'),
    url(r'^patient/family-add/$', views.FamilyMemberAdd.as_view(), name='family_add'),
    url(r'^patient/family-update/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<family_member_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.FamilyMemberUpdate.as_view(), name='family_update'),
    url(r'^patient/family-delete/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<family_member_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.FamilyMemberDelete.as_view(), name='family_delete'),
    url(r'^patient/family-detail/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<family_member_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.FamilyMemberDetails.as_view(), name='family_detail'),
    url(r'^patient/new-consultation/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.PatientConsultationView.as_view(), name='patient_consultation'),
    url(r'^patient/all-consultation/$', views.AllConsultationView.as_view(), name='all_patient_consultation'),
    url(r'^patient/new-observation/(?P<consultation_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<patient_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.PatientObservationView.as_view(), name='patient_observation'),

]
```

Comment: just updated with urls... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the technique described in the modelform docs under [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) to set the consultation ID from the request kwargs.

```
class PatientObservationView(CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.consultation_id_id = self.kwargs['consultation_id']
        return super(PatientObservationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

(The slightly stupid attribute name here is because you have called your ForeignKey field `consultation_id` instead of `consultation`, so the underlying db column is `consultation_id_id`. You really shouldn't do that.)

Note also you will need to remove `consultation_id` from the list of fields in the form as well as the template, otherwise it will never be valid.

Comment: Thanks alot. @daniel Roseman

return super() gives error:
Python Version 2.7 doesnt support this syntax, Super() should have an argument. So, how do i make this compatible with python2.7

Comment: Updated to 2.7 syntax.